# Tab bar button always show blue color in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I have added a `tabbar` in my app. I am showing 5 tabs at once. I am trying to make the custom colors of the tab bar. I have used following in my `TabBarController`

```
UITabBarItem *homeTab = [self.exposeTabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];
    UIImage *home_unselectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"home.png"];
    UIImage *home_selectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"home.png"];
    [homeTab setImage: [home_unselectedImage imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];
    [homeTab setSelectedImage: home_selectedImage];

    UITabBarItem *bookmarkTab = [self.exposeTabBar.items objectAtIndex:1];
    UIImage *bookmark_unselectedImage_ = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bookmark.png"];
    UIImage *bookmark_selectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bookmark.png"];
    [bookmarkTab setImage: [bookmark_unselectedImage_ imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];
    [bookmarkTab setSelectedImage: bookmark_selectedImage];

    UITabBarItem *postTab = [self.exposeTabBar.items objectAtIndex:2];
    UIImage *post_unselectedImage_ = [UIImage imageNamed:@"create-post.png"];
    UIImage *post_selectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"create-post_white.png"];
    [postTab setImage: [post_unselectedImage_ imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];
    [postTab setSelectedImage: post_selectedImage];

    UITabBarItem *notificationTab = [self.exposeTabBar.items objectAtIndex:3];
    UIImage *notification_unselectedImage_ = [UIImage imageNamed:@"notifications.png"];
    UIImage *notification_selectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"notifications_white.png"];
    [notificationTab setImage: [notification_unselectedImage_ imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];
    [notificationTab setSelectedImage: notification_selectedImage];

    UITabBarItem *profileTab = [self.exposeTabBar.items objectAtIndex:4];
    UIImage *profile_unselectedImage_ = [UIImage imageNamed:@"user-profile.png"];
    UIImage *profile_selectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"user-profile_white.png"];
    [profileTab setImage: [profile_unselectedImage_ imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];
    [profileTab setSelectedImage: profile_selectedImage];
```

For unselected Image it is showing the correct image but for selected image it is not showing the right image. It is showing some blue image for the icon.

Please tell how can I prevent this?

Answer (score 3):

Try using the tab bar appearance api method with clear color, in app delegate:

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

Answer (score 0):

try to change **tabBar color** and **tabBar tint**
example:

```
// Generate a black tab bar

self.tabBarController.tabBar.barTintColor = [UIColor blackColor];



// Set the selected icons and text tint color

self.tabBarController.tabBar.tintColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change tabBarController's "tabEdgeColor" and "topEdgeColor".

Or change the barTint or tint color of tabBar to clear color.

Answer (score 0):

For selected image, you should also set rendering mode, try this:

```
[homeTab setSelectedImage:[home_selectedImage imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom image for different color

```
tabBarItem1.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:"imag"]imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal ];
tabBarItem1.selectedImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"selected_image"]imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal ];
```